# Controllers e Rotas no node js

Tags: node.js, controller, back-end, express.js

Gostaria de saber, se implica alguma diferença entre usar somente **rotas**, ou **rotas** com **controllers** no ***node js***, alguém poderia me dar algum exemplo de como implementar rotas e controllers no node usando o ***express js***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre usar somente rotas, e usar rotas com controllers, a diferença é se precisas de lógica no servidor ou se estás a servir conteúdo estático que não precisa de lógica.

**O exemplo mais simples é usando o express para servir ficheiros estáticos**, sem rotas, sem lógica. Simplesmente mapeando:

```
app.use('/', express.static('minha-diretoria-root-do-site'))
```

Imagina que tens 2 ficheiros HTML que queres enviar para o cliente. Na prática tens sempre um controlador, mas neste caso ele faz tão pouco que vamos dizer que é só uma rota a servir ficheiros.

**Exemplo sem grande lógica que justifique um controlador:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../minha-diretoria-root-do-site', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/contacto', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../minha-diretoria-root-do-site', 'contacto.html'));
});
```

**Exemplo onde precisas de controlador**, que pode estar no mesmo ficheiro como o exemplo aqui, ou em ficheiros diferentes caso seja extenso:

```
app.get('/casas', (req, res) => {
    const query = 'SELECT name, price, rooms FROM houses';
    db.query(query, (err, rows) => {
        Promise.all([...rows].map(converterCambio)).then(items => {
            res.render('items', items);
        });
    });     
});
```

Neste ultimo exemplo fazes 2 passos assíncronos, e aqui a coisa pode complicar e ficar extensa, daí a necessidade do controlador. No exemplo imagino que envio para o renderizador, como o `ejs`, ou `Pug` para compilar a página com a array que lhe enviei.

Comment: Ok, mais isso também se aplica a operações com CRUD ?

Comment: @William explica melhor o que tens em mente. À partida para teres CRUD tens de ter um servidor com lógica para tratar esses pedidos. **C**riar uma entrada na base de dados precisa de lógica, **R**ead eventualmente pode ter menos lógica, mas tudo depende da complexidade da aplicação, **U**pdate precisa de lógica e **D**elete precisa de lógica.

Comment: seria algo simples como um cadastro de aluno, que necessitaria de operações com o banco com **select**, **update**, **insert** e **delete**, logo para ter uma organização melhor gostaria de implementar **controllers**.

Comment: @William controler não é mais que uma função com lógica como as que dei no exemplo. Podes ter mais ou menos código e ter no mesmo ficheiro ou não. Se houver alguma parte que não consigas implementar diz/pergunta, mas acho que isso é outra pergunta. Esta é _"diferença entre usar somente rotas, ou rotas com controllers"_. Tenho gosto (e certamente outros também) em ajudar/explicar mais.

Comment: Sim @Sergio, eu entendi que _**controllers**_ a grosso modo são funções porém, nesse caso a minha dúvida seria como pegar os dados de um formulário sendo que para isso usaria o por exemplo `app.get('aluno', function(res, req)` no _**controller**_ e quando chama-se na rota não haveria duplicação na rota?